# ServiceNow CSV file download via PHP

Tags: php, servicenow

I'm trying to initiate an automatically download a CSV file from ServiceNow via a URL.

I can paste the link `"https://<mycompany>.service-now.com/incident_list.do?CSV&sysparm_query=sys_updated_onBETWEENjavascript:gs.daysAgoStart(0)@javascript:gs.daysAgoEnd(0)&sysparm_orderby=sys_updated_on"` into a browser and automatically download the CSV file. I want to automate this. I've tried javascript but not getting around the Same Origin Policy. I'm trying PHP CURL with the following code.

```
<?php

include 'credentials.php';

function get_web_page( $url)
{
$header = array('content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 global $user;
 global $pass;

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
        CURLOPT_USERPWD        => "$user:$pass"

    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

$header['errno']   = $err;
$header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
$header['content'] = $content;
return $header;
}
$Content_Array = array();

$url = 'https://<mycompany>.service-now.com/incident_list.do?CSV&sysparm_query=sys_updated_onBETWEENjavascript:gs.daysAgoStart(0)@javascript:gs.daysAgoEnd(0)&sysparm_orderby=sys_updated_on';//
echo '<hr>'.$url.'<hr>';
$page =  get_web_page( $url );
echo $content = $page['content'];
echo '<pre>';
print_r($page);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

This returns an array of information but not what I need and it doesn't download anything. Hopefully I'm just missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere that you're specifying an output file. You can use the **CURLOPT_FILE** option and **fopen** to save the output automatically. Here's a stripped down example I borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742654/using-php-download-file-from-a-given-url-by-passing-username-and-password-for-ht):

```
$out = fopen($localfilename, 'wb');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($out);
```

Comment: I added the file output but it still doesn't work. I'm thinking I have an authentication problem where the script is missing a login point.